# Эпитеты, связанные со свойством «магнетизм»

Tags: прилагательные, синонимы, причастия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, эпитеты, которые можно использовать в значении их "магнитных" свойств.
Например, "притягательная" фактура материала.

Comment: http://www.synonymizer.ru/index.php?sword=%CF%F0%E8%F2%FF%E3%E0%F2%E5%EB%FC%ED%FB%E9  https://kartaslov.ru/синонимы-к-слову/притягательный

Comment: @Sharon нет, это не то. Здесь все слова могут быть использованы к чему угодно - и в большей степени к человеку - однако я ищу те, которые описывают действие "тела, обладающим собственным магнитным полем", по отношению к другим телам. То есть эпитеты нужны со склонностью к естественным наукам.
Прошу прощения за столь изъе.. кхм.. формулировки.

Comment: Тогда нужно привести предложение и контекст к нему.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, нас интересует, как я понимаю, вот *такой* [*магнетизм*](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/26940/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%CC%81%D0%B7%D0%BC) (МАС):
**4.** *перен. устар.*
Притягательная, покоряющая сила воздействия.
*А точно: силой магнетизма/ Стихов российских механизма/ Едва в то время не постиг/ Мой бестолковый ученик* (А. Пушкин. Евгений Онегин); *Был в нем некий магнетизм, который притягивал к нему сердца и симпатию людей труда* (М. Горький. В. И. Ленин).
**5.** *устар.*
Гипнотическое внушение.
*Я совсем не против народной медицины и верю ей, особенно в соединении с магнетизмом* (С. Аксаков. Воспоминания); *Не лежит у меня душа к этим господам, которые беседуют с духами и лечат баб магнетизмом* (А. Чехов. Ариадна).

Думаю, что главное слово указано [в словаре Ожегова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/101850): **магнетический**.

Ещё (и прилагательные, и причастия):
гипнотический (гипнотизирующий), колдовской (околдовывающий), чарующий (очаровывающий), завораживающий, манящий, неотразимый, завлекающий (увлекающий), притягательный (притягивающий), захватывающий...

Comment: Нет, виноват. Здесь я все-таки ищу прилагательные-синонимы к причастию "притягивающий", которые можно использовать "эвфеместично", но из смысла которых будет понятно, что речь о "теле, обладающим собственным магнитным полем".
Короче, речь не о свойствах человека - или о свойствах иных тел, притягивающих внимание человека - сколько о физических свойствах тел, способных притягивать - в прямом смысле - другие к себе тела.
Например, металлы - на Земле, иные тела собственной гравитацией - вне земного пространства.

Comment: Приветствую вас на сайте, *Aleksey*! Ну... Во-первых, *эвфем**и**стично*. Во-вторых, не стоит заключать в кавычки (как цитату) выражение, содержащее ошибку (правильно: *теле, обладающ**е**м собственным магнитным полем*). В-третьих, тогда не понимаю вас. Если глаза по-настоящему притягиваются друг к другу (или к какой-то ещё паре глаз), то *каковы* же они? Это глаза роботов — металлические, **намагниченные**?

Comment: Или **магнитные** — обладающие свойствами магнита?

Answer (score 0):

Существует понятие  **[магнитная текстура](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_physics/1558/%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%93%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%AF)**, связанное с внутренним строением вещества, а **фактура** определяется по **внешнему** виду материала.

В любом случае лучше использовать относительное прилагательное ***магнитный*** с широким спектром значений. Слово ***магнетический*** в этом смысле в ряде словарей считается **устаревшим**, оно в основном применяется в переносном, а не прямом значении (связанным с магнитом и магнетизмом). Поэтому в терминологии обычно используется  слово ***магнитный.***

Можно сказать: ***магнитная** сила, сила **притяжения**.*  Других **синонимов** в этой области скорее нет. При записи **в кавычках** можно: притягательный, притягивающий".

**Словарный материал**

**МАГНЕТИЧЕСКИЙ**, 1. прил. к магнетизм в 1 ·знач. (физ.). Магнетические явления. В словаре Ушакова и Ефремовой. Но в других источниках считается устаревшим.

**МАГНИТ**, -а; м. [греч. Magnēs]. 1. Тело, притягивающее железные и стальные предметы или отталкивающее их, благодаря действию своего магнитного поля. Искусственный м. 2. Разг. О том, что обладает притягательной силой, привлекает к себе. **Магнитный**, -ая, -ое (1 зн.).

**МАГНЕТИЗМ**, -а; м. [франц. magnetisme]. 1. Свойство магнита, а также проводника с электрическим током притягивать к себе или отталкивать от себя некоторые тела. Изучение магнетизма. 2. Учение о магнитных явлениях и свойствах тел. Курс магнетизма. 3. Книжн. Притягательная, покоряющая сила воздействия. М. личности. М. души. 4. Гипнотическое внушение. Лечить магнетизмом. **Магнетический, -ая, -ое. Устар. (3-4 зн.)**. М-ое влияние. М-ие глаза. М-ая сила.

**ТЕКСТУРА**, -ы; ж. [от лат. textura — ткань, связь, строение]. Спец. Характер строения твёрдого вещества, расположения его составных частей (кристаллов, зёрен и т.п.). Перламутровая т. Т. горных пород. Т. древесины (естественный рисунок разреза древесины). Текстурный, -ая, -ое.

**ФАКТУРА,** -ы; ж. [от лат. factura — обработка, строение]. 1. Характер обработки, строения какого-л. материала, определяющие его внешний вид. Гладкая, ворсистая ф. ткани. Интересная ф. дерева. Ф. стекла, гранита.